# How to vertically center text when selecting by mouse pointer in HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center text when selecting them with the mouse pointer but I can't get it to work.

Here is my text when it's not vertically centered:
[image]

```css
html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  -o-tab-size: 4;
  tab-size: 4;
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h1>Apple and Orange</h1>
```

Comment: This is a "problem" with the line-height. The line-height distribution is dependent on the font you are using. So this in fact isn't an error.

Comment: @QuentinAlbert can you suggest me some fonts that don't cause the problem i'm having?

Comment: @Epple you dont need to call people twice, There is no specific font-family that has no line height, as the line height is determined by the CSS property line-height. However, you can set the line height for any font-family by using CSS. Best you can do is `line-height: normal;  or
   line-height: 1;`

Comment: If you use @font-face you can maybe use `ascent-override` or `descent-override` to adjust how the font sits on the baseline. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face